# Question about Peierls Droplets argument

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

I am trying to understand the logic of considering Peierls droplets. The basic idea is that the entropy and energy of the loop are proportional to its length L ([see Tong's lectures, p.161](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf)). As a result, in the thermodynamic limit, we find that a low-temperature (ordered phase) exists up to a certain critical temperature (order parameter = constant) $T_c$, and at $T > T_c$ *the ordered phase begins to smoothly disorder* (the order parameter smoothly changes with temperature). But in reality we have a different situation, in a sense, the opposite: A completely disordered phase with zero average energy per spin exists above a certain critical temperature, and *begins to smoothly order* with decreasing temperature. Is there any way to explain the discrepancy of this model?

Comment: How are those two statements mutually exclusive? I don't see why they can't both be true.

Comment: Real situation,  see for example here (Figure 102, order parameter - mean ehergy per spin):  http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node110.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question, as it phrases Peierls' argument as a general, but rough (basically heuristic) thermodynamic type argument (which it is not, even though it is often presented as one). In any case, I'll try to address some issues that might help.

---

My main point is that Peierls' contour argument does not tell you anything about the phase transition from the paramagnetic phase to the ferromagnetic phase, only that the latter exists at sufficiently low temperatures.

This can be seen by observing that in dimensions $3$ and more, the $-$ spins percolate in the $+$ phase for temperatures $T$ satisfying $T_0<T<T_c$ for some $T_0$ depending on the dimension. So, the probability of having an infinitely large "droplet" surrounding a given point is strictly positive when $T$ satisfies $T_0<T<T_c$. This means that Peierls' argument cannot be applied at a temperature above $T_0$ and thus cannot detect the transition occurring at $T_c$.

Of course, one might try to resort to more sophisticated variants. Say, by introducing block-spins of a suitable size $R(T)$ (partition the system in boxes of size $R(T)$ and declare a box to be of type $+$ if you see something typical of the $+$ phase inside, of type $-$ if you see something typical of the $-$ phase inside, and $0$ otherwise). Peierls contours defined in terms of such block spins would be fine. Notice, however, that $R(T)$ will have to diverge as $T$ gets close to $T_c$, so that, again, Peierls' argument will not tell you anything about the transition at $T_c$.

---

Even in dimension $2$, where $T_0=T_c$, I don't get your question. The typical diameter of a droplet surrounding a given point diverges as $T$ approaches $T_c$ in this case. So Peierls' argument certainly does not imply that the order parameter is constant for $T<T_c$, nor that it smoothly changes for $T>T_c$. Indeed, the opposite is true: the order parameter smoothly decreases to $0$ as $T$ increases towards $T_c$, and remains identically $0$ at and above $T_c$.

Comment: * So Peierls' argument certainly does not imply that the order parameter is constant for T<Tc*  - $Z$ is *convergent* for T<Tc and divergent at T>Tc so  in the thermodynamic limit order parameter (e.g.   mean energy per spin)  is strictly constant and equal to zero at T<Tc, and changes at T>Tc since Z became divergent

Comment: First, as I explain above, it is not true that the temperature at which the sum diverges coincides with $T_c$ (it is strictly smaller). Second, even when it converges, it tells you only that the magnetization density is nonzero, but its value depends on $T$ (the less costly the contours, the lower the magnetization density).

Comment: Rather than the very informal discussion given in the lecture notes you refer to (and in many other places), I recommend that you either read about Peierls' argument directly from Peierls' original paper, or from one of the many places where it is discussed in detail (for instance, Section 3.7.2 of [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook)). What this argument actually tells you should be clearer then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, I will try to clarify the question in the way you specified.

Comment: Maybe I understand where you get the very strange claim that the order parameter identically vanishes when $T<T_c$: you do realize that there is a positive density of Peierls contours in a configuration of the Ising model? So, typical contours being finite by no means implies that the energy per spin is zero!

Comment: *typical contours being finite* I mean its mean value <L> is zero at T<Tc (this follows from minimizing free energy  -(aL-2bJL) (p.161)

Comment: [I removed a comment in which I misunderstood your misunderstanding ;) ...]

Comment: f you really want to make sense of the expected length of the contour in the simple setting of the lecture notes you refer to, then you should consider the probability measure that associates to contours of length $L$ a probability proportional to $\exp(aL-2bJL)$ (with your notations above). Then, the expected value of $L$ under this measure is certainly not $0$.

Comment: More explicitly: in the simple setting of the lecture notes you refer to, you should compute $\langle L\rangle = (1/Z) \sum_L L e^{\alpha L-2\beta L}$. This is certainly not $0$!

Comment: Yes, in this case minimization -(aL-2bJL) gives Lmin=0 that of course not coinsed with <L>, I was wrong, but nevertheless under $L_{sys}\rightarrow \infty$  
 $ \frac{Log(Z)} {L_{sys}} \rightarrow 0$,  $\beta > \alpha/ 2J$ and 
$ \frac{Log(Z)} {L_{sys}} \rightarrow (\alpha-2\beta J) $, $\beta < \alpha/ 2J$, were $L_{sys}$ is the size of the system

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to compute in this way. The Peierls argument is not about free energy (whatever the lecture notes say). What the Peierls argument tells you is that when the sum converges and is small enough, you can deduce that there is a nonzero magnetization density. That's all. The rest is at best heuristic (and mostly hand waving).

Comment: I think that you are trying to extract information from this extremely rough argument that the latter cannot provide. This is why you obtain irrelevant results. Playing with rough heuristic arguments to get a feeling of what happens can be very useful, but you have to be careful not to ask for more than they can yield.